# An alternative proof of the Łojasiewicz inequality

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

Is there a "brute force proof" of the Łojasiewicz inequality? By "brute force" I mean a proof without introducing the machinery of semianalytic sets and so on but only using elementary results (*i.e.*, standard Calculus 1+2). I admit i hadn't time to think about it properly, I thought I could prove it first for homogeneous polynomials (and I got stuck) and then extend the result to analytic functions, but I could be wrong... To avoid misunderstandings I recall here the statement of the Łojasiewicz inequality.

Let $f\in C^{\omega}(B_{1},\mathbb{R})$ (real analytic function on the open unit ball centered at the origin) then there are $\alpha\in (0,1)$, $C>0$ and $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small such that  $\forall x\in B_{\varepsilon}$ the following holds true:
$$|f(x)-f(0)|^{\alpha}\leq C|\nabla f(x)|.$$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

[Rate of decay to equilibrium in some semilinear parabolic equations](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00028-003-1112-8), Alain Haraux, Mohamed Ali Jendoubi, Otared Kavian (2003).

I would think section 2, "A direct proof of the Lojasiewicz inequality" has what you're looking for:

> In this paper we are going to present an elementary proof of the
>   Lojasiewicz inequality in the framework of an energy functional, under
>   simple circumstances but without assuming the analyticity of the
>   nonlinearity of the function $f$.

An alternative (somewhat less "direct") proof is given in [On the Łojasiewicz–Simon gradient inequality](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123602001027), Ralph Chill (2003).

Comment: I think that in the paper that you mentioned they deal with a very special case of the \Lojasewicz  inequality when the function $f$ has a *nondegenerate* critical point at the origin.

Comment: for a nondegenerate critical point the exponent $\alpha=1/2$; that is theorem 2.1 in the paper; theorems 2.2 and 2.5 address the more general case $\alpha\in[1/2,1)$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! At the moment i don't have access to these papers so i can't check if they are what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no elementary proof of that result even for polynomials of 2 variables. The proof of this result an be reduced to a more elementary one (the case of monomials) by using the theory of sigularities, but this is not at all elementary, cf. the recent works of Paul Feehan.